# Javascript if statement for parameters inside array

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I am having trouble with coding **stripe checkout with my pricing table that has a discount for annual subscriptions**.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I was thinking of doing it by adding an if statement in the JavaScript function, but how can I add an if statement to only include discounts parameter if something else is true?  For example the working code is:

```
const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    payment_method_types: [
      'card',
    ],
    line_items: [
      {
        price: product.priceid,
        quantity: 1,
      },
    ],
    mode: 'subscription',
    discounts: [{
      coupon: 'abc123',
    }],
    success_url: `${process.env.URL}` + `/success.html`,
    cancel_url: `${process.env.URL}` + product.cancelurl,
  });
```

In the above example, if discounts is included as a parameter, then coupon needs to be a valid input or else the function fails.  To run without any coupons, the entire discounts parameter needs to be left out. So I was hoping to be able to only include discounts parameter using an if statement, something like:

```
if (true) {
  discounts: [{
      coupon: 'abc123',
    }],
}
```

Alternatively, I also tried to put the entire function into an if statement, but that also fails syntax, like this:

```
if (true) {
  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    payment_method_types: [
      'card',
    ],
    line_items: [
      {
        price: product.priceid,
        quantity: 1,
      },
    ],
    mode: 'subscription',
    discounts: [{
      coupon: 'abc123',
    }],
    success_url: `${process.env.URL}` + `/success.html`,
    cancel_url: `${process.env.URL}` + product.cancelurl,
  });
} else {
  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    payment_method_types: [
      'card',
    ],
    line_items: [
      {
        price: product.priceid,
        quantity: 1,
      },
    ],
    mode: 'subscription',
    success_url: `${process.env.URL}` + `/success.html`,
    cancel_url: `${process.env.URL}` + product.cancelurl,
  });
}
```

Can anyone help with how I could fix the code so that the if statements work, or alternatively suggest a better way to create a pricing table with annual discounts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a ternary operator in this case:

```js
{
    discounts: true ? [{ coupon: 'abc123' }] : undefined
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Works perfectly, and thank you for teaching me how ternary operator works!

Answer (score 0):

Create the options object first, add the property conditionally, then call the function.

```js
const options = {
  payment_method_types: [
    'card',
  ],
  line_items: [{
    price: product.priceid,
    quantity: 1,
  }, ],
  mode: 'subscription',
  success_url: `${process.env.URL}` + `/success.html`,
  cancel_url: `${process.env.URL}` + product.cancelurl,
};

if (condition) {
  options.discounts = [{
    coupon: 'abc123',
  }];
};

const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create(options);
```